# Is the birth details or Janam Kundali or horoscope of Sri Krishna mentioned in any Scripture?

Tags: krishna, astrology, horoscopes, kundali

Is Sri Krishna's authentic Janam Kundali or birth details (date of birth, place of birth and time of birth) available? Is it mentioned in any Puranas or any scripture?

Comment: I have the jataka of Krsna which is from Achyutananda tradition of Jyotish. As you know Shri Achyutananda was initiated by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, therefore it's  a Vaishnava Parampara.  Will that be an accurate answer (the jataka)?

Comment: A 'tradition' in Jyotish refers to a lineage of masters named after their primordial guru (Bhrigu, Achyutananda, etc). And the term 'school' shouldn't be used as Jamini Maharishi was himself from the Parasara 'school'. Pt. Sanjay Rath and Visti Larsen hail from the Achyutananda tradition. And BSP is not a school, but an activation technique.

Comment: Parampara/Tradition Guru is by definition the first Guru of the Parampara and not any 'founder of a system'. And yes I know that Parashara and Jamini systems are different, I just pointed out that they belong to the same lineage of masters, i.e. Jamini Maharishi was from parampara of Parashara rishi himself. That's why using the term Parashara and Jamini 'school' is ambiguous.  Comment on what's said, and don't back off in points where you commit mistakes. I've quite a good idea about what I'm talking about.

Comment: https://www.scienceoflight.net/science-of-light-course/astrology-lineage/.

Comment: I've studied from Bhrigu and Achyutananda Parampara. Perhaps you've studied Jyotish from YouTube. Your ignorance is understandable.

Comment: Oof, how bad it hurts to loose an argument xD.

Comment: @Amritendu You should be nice to your fellow users. Please visit help section to learn more. Also I feel enough proof has given by Swapnil to support his claim.